# vagrant up command return errors

Tags: vagrant

I am setting up a fast hadoop cluster development envirment with vagrant, but met error when "vagrant up".

I have tried "vagrant plugin install vagrant-centos7_fix", but no luck.

followings are these errors:

```
C:/zjsw/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/net-sftp-2.1.2/lib/net/sftp/response.rb:70:in `block in <class:Response>': undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from C:/zjsw/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/net-sftp-2.1.2/lib/net/sftp/response.rb:68:in `each'
        from C:/zjsw/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/net-sftp-2.1.2/lib/net/sftp/response.rb:68:in `inject'
        from C:/zjsw/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/net-sftp-2.1.2/lib/net/sftp/response.rb:68:in `<class:Response>'
        from C:/zjsw/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/net-sftp-2.1.2/lib/net/sftp/response.rb:16:in `<module:SFTP>'
        from C:/zjsw/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/net-sftp-2.1.2/lib/net/sftp/response.rb:3:in `<module:Net>'
        from C:/zjsw/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/net-sftp-2.1.2/lib/net/sftp/response.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/zjsw/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/zjsw/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/zjsw/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/net-sftp-2.1.2/lib/net/sftp/request.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/zjsw/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/zjsw/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/zjsw/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/net-sftp-2.1.2/lib/net/sftp/session.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/zjsw/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/zjsw/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/zjsw/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/net-sftp-2.1.2/lib/net/sftp.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/zjsw/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/zjsw/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/zjsw/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/vagrant-2.2.4/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/zjsw/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/zjsw/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/zjsw/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/vagrant-2.2.4/plugins/communicators/ssh/plugin.rb:14:in `block in <class:Plugin>'
        from C:/zjsw/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/vagrant-2.2.4/lib/vagrant/registry.rb:27:in `get'
        from C:/zjsw/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/vagrant-2.2.4/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:259:in `communicate'
        from C:/zjsw/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.4/gems/vagrant-2.2.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/wait_for_communicator.rb:16:in `block in call'
```